# PHP - Hold Session variable from Select Option box to every page

Tags: php, variables, session, html-select

I seem to be having a problem and after hours of searching and messing with different ideas I can't seem to come up with this seems to be simple PHP Session problem with my Select Options menu.

All I want to do is simple have the selected Hotel Name from the dropdown hold till it is changed, and this goes for every page. So I thought, of yea lets just use Sessions. Doesn't seem to work very well as it keeps refreshing the data. Here is my code, and maybe one of you guys can come up with a solution. I would really appreciate it!

We are using a json file to populate the menu that we get by using a CURL to call the data and then decode the json.

Here is the dropdown code:

```
<select id="hotelSelected" name="hotelSelected">
<?php
sort($hotelName);
foreach($hotelName as $value):
echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.ucfirst($value).'</option>';
endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

And then I tried to create a session by doing this:

```
$_SESSION['hotelName'] = $hotelName;
```

And now I need this session to carry on every page. And possibly echo on certain pages by possibly using this:

```
echo $_SESSION['hotelName'];
```

Any help is appreciated or redirect me to a forum that can fix my problem. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `session_start();` at the top of every PHP file which uses sessions. 
Also if you have a form contains `SELECT` tag , after submitting the form you should use `$_POST['hotelSelected']` for grabbing tha value of option selected by user.

EDIT 1:

```
    <select id="hotelSelected" name="hotelSelected">
    <?php
    sort($hotelName);
    foreach($hotelName as $key=>$value):
    echo '<option value=($_SESSION['hotelname'][$key]):"'.$_SESSION['hotelname'][$key].'"'.ucfirst($_SESSION['hotelname'][$key]).'?"'.$value.'"'.ucfirst($value).'</option>';
    endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<?php
    $_SESSION['hotelname']=$hotelname;
```

Comment: I do have that of course, I'm having a problem posting this on the select box as on refresh it does not grab the right data.

Comment: This could work, as soon as we get the back end up and running again I will implement this and try it.

Comment: This didn't work, it won't keep it and keeps refreshing the list.

Answer (score 0):

### html

```
<select id="hotelSelected" name="hotelSelected" onchange="run(this)">
<?php
    sort($hotelName);
    foreach($hotelName as $value):
        echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.ucfirst($value).'</option>';
    endforeach; 
?>
</select>
```

### javascript

```
function run(sel) {
    var i = sel.selectedIndex;
    if (i != -1) {
        $.post('updatesession.php', {id:i}, function(){
        alert('Session Updated!');
    });
    }
}
```

### updatesession.php

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['hotelName']=id;
}
```

Comment: This actually makes sense how you did this, but I am coming across an issue where the session isn't holding and it resets every time. Pulling from a JSON I feel like it is refreshing every time and not holding where it was.

Comment: This did not work, sorry for such a late reply. It kept refreshing the value within the select list, and now I have a bigger dilema with two lists. I have to have one selected, then that populates the second list, and now I need to hold the variables of both.